# How to connect to azure key vault using service principal and .pem file in ansible-plabook

Tags: azure, ansible, azure-keyvault

I was trying to use ansible to get/set secrets in azure key vault. in azure_rm_keyvaultsecret module we have only secret argument to provide credentials for the service principal. but our requirement is to use .pem file to authenticate  the Service principal
so can some one help us with the following please.

1. how to provide a .pem file to authenticate the service principal to connect Azure key vault.
2. is there any other way/ module to achieve our requirement

Answer (score 0):

You can sign in to Azure with Service principal before you run your tasks or playbook with az login

To sign in to Azure  with service principal with certificate, please  use  the  below command :

**az login --service-principal -u  -p </path/to/cert/pem/file > --tenant**

Reference :
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/azure/azcollection/azure_rm_keyvaultsecret_info_module.html
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/authenticate-azure-cli?view=azure-cli-latest